# Future Warning with gdebi while installing some packages

Tags: 19.04, deb, gdebi

I installed gdebi and then tried to install some .deb with it. The first time I tried installing them, it didn't, showing these:

```
/usr/bin/gdebi:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower()
```

Tried again, using gdebi and it installed, but the message still appeared after prompting me if I wanted to install.

Since it says it's a future warning, should I be worried?

Comment: Where does it say 'error'? Error and warning are not the same.

Comment: It looks like it's just a warning.  Also note that some warnings are for the developer to see and not you -- it might be a reminder to be careful of something that will become obsolete, etc.  Anyway, it sounds like you tried installing twice and the first time it didn't work?  You probably got an error message and not just the warning above.  You would need to provide that if someone is to help you better.  The warning itself seems harmless and meant for the developer.

Comment: Quoting the string in the findall method like here:
[https://forums.solydxk.com/viewtopic.php?t=7531](https://forums.solydxk.com/viewtopic.php?t=7531)
solved the issue for me =)

Comment: Great.  i suppose you refer to `c = findall("\[(\S+)/\S+\]", msg)[0].lower()`.  It is best to add this ibn your ansewer instead of just giving a link.  So, even if the linked document disappears, your answer remains valid (and spares time for the reader to scan the page and find which part you meant.)

Comment: Note, that nowadays I'd call `gdebi` deprecated, because `apt` can install from a local file. To make it recognize arguments as local files just prefix the path with either `./` or `/`. So, like, instead of `sudo apt install my_file.deb` you have to write `sudo apt install ./my_file.deb`.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo sed -i 's|"\[\[.*\]"|"[\\[(](\\S+)/\\S+[\\])]"|' /usr/share/gdebi/gdebi
sudo sed -i 's|"\[\[.*\]"|"[\\[(](\\S+)/\\S+[\\])]"|' /usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py
```

Am on 20.04.01 and this fixed the issue

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Could you clarify what you do in your post?  Is it a definitive correction or a just a patch?